# Android sample project

Tags: android, sample

I would like to know how to get this sample

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example

I'm trying to use a Loader, the link takes me to a "Sample section" and does not start any donwloads, I can try to donwload the samples from the SDK manager but I don't know in what SDK this specific sample is.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where android samples are found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235997/where-android-samples-are-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  code is available on github and can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/samples/android/+/android-4.4_r1.1/content/LoaderCursor/src/com/example/android/content/loadercursor/CursorLoaderListFragment.java).